# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm getting **object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role** exception while trying to insert some values in table using **hibernate**
related dependencies in pom.xml are

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Role.java is

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id = 0;

private String name = null;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<User> users = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
} }
```

User.java is

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id = 0;

private String name = null;
private String email = null;
private String password = null;

@ManyToMany
private List<Role> roles = null;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<Blog> blogs = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
    return blogs;
}

public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
    this.blogs = blogs;
}}
```

I'm using repository as mentioned in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBMDgbtlNoE), are

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.entity.Role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {

}
```

and

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

and InitDbService.java is

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class InitDbService {

    @Autowired
    private BlogRepository blogRepository = null;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository = null;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository = null;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository = null;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Role roleUser = new Role();
        roleUser.setName("ROLE_USER");
        roleRepository.save(roleUser);

        Role roleAdmin = new Role();
        roleAdmin.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        roleRepository.save(roleAdmin);

        User userAdmin = new User();
        userAdmin.setName("admin");

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();       
        roles.add(roleAdmin);
        roles.add(roleUser);

        userAdmin.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(userAdmin);

        //Test insert in to DB
        Blog javaBlog = new Blog();
        javaBlog.setName("Java Blog");
        javaBlog.setUrl("http://security.stackexchange.com/");
        javaBlog.setUser(userAdmin);
        blogRepository.save(javaBlog);

        Item item1 = new Item();
        item1.setTitle("Java Blog");
        item1.setBlog(javaBlog);
        item1.setLink("http://security.stackexchange.com/");
        item1.setPublishedDate(new Date());
        itemRepository.save(item1);


        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.setTitle("Java Blog two");
        item2.setBlog(javaBlog);
        item2.setLink("http://security.stackexchange.com/");
        item2.setPublishedDate(new Date());
        itemRepository.save(item2);
    }

}
```

I have seen [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be/2302814#2302814), but still getting this error my console out put is

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Hibernate: alter table Blog drop constraint FK_thdkoy0q7vcgc5hay9wb99vnh
Hibernate: alter table Item drop constraint FK_il3204s0mf6d1m8am8f5768ah
Hibernate: alter table Role_User drop constraint FK_iha4m965rutefhrl4f2pvko39
Hibernate: alter table Role_User drop constraint FK_1rtsbyk364hixsho0345aj4sd
Hibernate: alter table User_Role drop constraint FK_tc5k40i3kit8944syrd366vy1
Hibernate: alter table User_Role drop constraint FK_dv4w2xni693cg4ibi3fo1fkk6
Hibernate: drop table Blog if exists
Hibernate: drop table Item if exists
Hibernate: drop table Role if exists
Hibernate: drop table Role_User if exists
Hibernate: drop table User if exists
Hibernate: drop table User_Role if exists
Hibernate: create table Blog (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), name varchar(255), url varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Item (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), description varchar(255), link varchar(255), published_date timestamp, title varchar(255), blog_id integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Role (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Role_User (Role_id integer not null, users_id integer not null)
Hibernate: create table User (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), email varchar(255), name varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table User_Role (User_id integer not null, roles_id integer not null)
Hibernate: alter table Blog add constraint FK_thdkoy0q7vcgc5hay9wb99vnh foreign key (user_id) references User
Hibernate: alter table Item add constraint FK_il3204s0mf6d1m8am8f5768ah foreign key (blog_id) references Blog
Hibernate: alter table Role_User add constraint FK_iha4m965rutefhrl4f2pvko39 foreign key (users_id) references User
Hibernate: alter table Role_User add constraint FK_1rtsbyk364hixsho0345aj4sd foreign key (Role_id) references Role
Hibernate: alter table User_Role add constraint FK_tc5k40i3kit8944syrd366vy1 foreign key (roles_id) references Role
Hibernate: alter table User_Role add constraint FK_dv4w2xni693cg4ibi3fo1fkk6 foreign key (User_id) references User
Hibernate: insert into Role (id, name) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Role (id, name) values (default, ?)
Hibernate: insert into User (id, email, name, password) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into User_Role (User_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
Jul 9, 2015 3:29:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initDbService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:122)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy34.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.service.InitDbService.init(InitDbService.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.Role
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 47 more
```

any better solution to this issue Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might make changes in `@Entity` classes like these are

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id = 0;

private String name = null;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable
private List<User> users = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
} }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id = 0;

private String name = null;
private String email = null;
private String password = null;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Role> roles = null;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<Blog> blogs = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
    return blogs;
}

public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
    this.blogs = blogs;
}}
```

So on and so forth as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be/2302814#2302814). it might solve your issue!
try this and let me know any issue/success.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few threads on this topic, most pointing to `CASCADE = ALL` as the answer.  It didn't work for me, and I was only getting the error intermittently.  I began to think the cascading wasn't working and stumbled on this [article](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-lazy-mode-doesnt-work-with-spring-boot/1535), which pointed me to `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`, which led me to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot/48222934#48222934).

So, I set open-in-view to false, and got a bunch of `LazyInitializationException` errors, and that led me to this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/).  To short cut it and quickly remove the LazyInitializationExceptions, I just set the `FETCH` to `EAGER` to see if it worked... and it did.  I think.  Because the error was always intermittent, it is hard to say for sure.

I am still looking into what is going on, but wanted to throw this out there in case someone is struggling with the standard answer of setting the cascade.

My entity model was fairly standard, 1-to-many parent to child.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TRIP", schema="HIKES")
public class Trip implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trip", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<EquipListItem> equipmentList;
...
```

The method I was calling that caused the unsaved transient instance exception was on the parent and would created a new instance of the child and add it to the Collection.

```
public void addEquipment(int wanted, final GearItem item) {
    if(null == equipmentList) {
        // Create list.
        equipmentList = new ArrayList<EquipListItem>();
    }
    equipmentList.add(new EquipListItem(this, item, wanted));
}
```

Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Did you manage to find the reason why it was intermittent after all? I am facing something similar