# How can I determine whether I am in a transaction in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with persistence in a Spring service. A Rest-Controller R receives a request, and calls a service S via a complex way through some layers of code. The service method in S declares a transaction; this should be the first time a transaction should be started.
But the service behaves like a transaction already had been started before, and some of my data objects would be part of the session (which they must not).
How can I determine if a transaction is already active? I have tried to inject EntityManager and/or JpaTransactionManager; but both seem to be of no help.

How can I check whether I am in a transaction or not?

I want to be sure of that before I go hunting through all these layers searching for possible suspects.

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but it sounds like you've fallen victim to Open Session In View (OSIV) just like us. It is enabled by default (for historical reasons). Check [another thread in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot) for more details.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can check if transaction is active using `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`. But you should call it before a service method executing.

Also you can get status of current transaction using

```
TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
```

Besides, maybe a good point for you is to enable logging of transactions.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Comment: What if I get TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() = true, but TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() throws: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope?

Comment: how to convert these statements to log4j2 version log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG

Comment: @AndriiBobrov Did you find the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager#isActualTransactionActive
```