# Java: calling public transactional method from a private method

Tags: java, spring

I have two classes

```
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    private void test() {
        myService.writeToDb();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void writeToDb() {
        // do db related stuff
    }
}
```

I want to know if calling a method test() (which is a **private** method) from MyTest class would create a transaction.

P.S

I'm using Spring Boot. And Java 17.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine whether I am in a transaction in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629935/how-can-i-determine-whether-i-am-in-a-transaction-in-spring)

Comment: I would expect some technical explanation on why / why not this piece of could would run in a transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, whether you call the method of another object from a public or private method inside yours is an implementation detail. From callee's point of view, it's the same, it is not even aware of the caller's context.

Spring AOP uses [the Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to handle those scenarios. It means you are not directly receiving a `MyService` bean, but a `MyServiceSpringCreatedProxy` (not the actual name, check in debug mode and you'll see), which is actually handling transactions around methods.

So as long as the call passes through the Spring's proxy, the `@Transactional` will be accounted for as expected. Bear in mind that it doesn't mean a new transaction is open, it depends if another already exists and your configuration.

However, any self call (to a public or a private method) would not pass through the proxy and then `@Transactional` would not be working.

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

   // can be private, public or whatever
    public void callRelatedStuff() {
       //self call, no transactional work done
       writeToDb();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void writeToDb() {
        // do db related stuff
    }
}
```