# Are Spring @Controller rsp. @RestController transactional with spring-data-jpa repositories? It looks like it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am following the Spring-boot tutorial at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start which uses the `spring-boot-starter-web` as well as the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` without customization. My `spring-boot-starter-parent` -version is `1.5.10.RELEASE`.

It is a simple REST-Api for a simple `Book`-entity backed by a spring-data-jpa `Repository` 
I am experimenting with different implementations of the delete-method of the `@RestController`.
When calling the sequence

```
Book book = repo.findOne((Long)1L);
repo.delete(book);
```

in the `main()`-method of the SpringBoot-application there will be 2 `select`-statements generated by JPA/Hibernate as can be seen in the log (abbreviated for clarity):

```
select book0_.id (...) from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
select book0_.id (...) from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
delete from book where id=?
```

This is the expected behaviour: Outside of a transaction these 2 calls will trigger a transaction each. Furthermore, since `EntityManager.remove()` only accepts attached/managed entities, the spring-data `delete()`-implementation does an `EntityManager-find()` before calling `EntityManager.remove()` on the result of the `find()`.
The same sequence in the `@RestController`-annotated class however will only call `select` once. Furthermore, a little experiment strongly suggests that this method runs inside a transaction and that the persistence-context of some EntityManager is apparently active here:

```
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
    void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        Book book = repo.findOne((Long)id);
        repo.delete(book);
        System.out.println(book);
        book.setTitle("XXX");
        Book book2 = repo.findOne((Long)id);
        System.out.println(book2);
        repo.delete(id);
    }
```

The log-output when called with a valid `id` is (again, abbreviated for clarity):

```
select book0_.id as id1_0_0_(...) from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
Book [id=1, title=Spring Boot, author=Chris]
Book [id=1, title=XXX, author=Chris]
delete from book where id=?
```

It is my understanding (as well as the result of extensive seach on stackoverflow and the rest of the internet) that `@Controller`-methods run *outside* of a transaction. Indeed, there is discussion whether a @Controller should or should not be `@Transactional`. My `@Controller` isn't.

So how is this observed behaviour possible?
And is there some documentation explaining this?

For completeness' sake, here are class-definitions:
The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books/")
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    BookRepository repo;

    (...)

 @DeleteMapping("{id}")
        void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
(...) see above
    }
```

The spring-data-jpa interface:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long>{
    List<Book> findByTitle(String title);
    Optional<Book> findOne(long id);
}
```

The SpringBoot-application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses= {SimpleController.class}) 
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses={Book.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses= {BookRepository.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
                              SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: No the are not transactional there is, by default, however the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` which is active by default and hence you will have a single shared `EntityManager`.

Comment: if you go to /actuator/beans - do you see a PlatformTransactionManager bean? CrudRepository methods are transactional by default (e.g. delete)

Answer (score 2):

@M.Deinum Thank you for pointing me to the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`-issue. I now found the apparently infamous OSIV/OEMIV (open session in view/open EntityManager in view)-discussion (i.e. should the `EntityManager` be still open in the controller-methods and thus prevent `LazyLoading`-issues or should, on the contrary, these issues be exposed?

AND: What should the default be? This link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107 has the discussion. Therein, a blog-entry arguing against  OSIV/OEMIV is discussed: 
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/
I was pointed to this by this stackoverflow-question:
[What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)
To sum up: The default is OSIV/OEMIV but it can be easily toggled using the application.properties property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`
The discussion comes to the conclusion that OSIV/OEMIV  should remain the default for SpringBoot. It should however be documented better (its existence is hard to find; only in an appendix of a documentation)

I now have experimented with `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` and it does indeed work as advertised.