# When does a object become detached in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a service that is using a Spring Data Repository to retrieve an object.  The service is NOT marked as transactional, thus I assumed that any object returned from the repository would be detached since the transaction would be scoped to the repository.  However, it seems as though the object is NOT detached which surprises me.  Here is a code sample:

```
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  private MyRepository repo;
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  /**
   * Updates a persisted entity based on the given DTO representation.
   */
  public MyObjectDto update(MyObjectDto dto) {
    MyObjectJpa existing = repo.findOne(dto.getId());

    entityManager.isJoinedToTransaction(); // returns false so no transaction should be active in this scope I would assume
    entityManager.contains(existing); // this returns true, but I don't know why

    if (existing != null) {
      MyObjectJpa updated = toJpa(dto);

      // calling repo.save(..) modifies the state of 'existing' object which surpised me
      MyObjectDto updatedDto = toDto(repo.save(updated));
      return updatedDto;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Why is the 'existing' object in my code sample still managed by the entityManager even though my service method is not marked as transactional (i.e. not using the @Transactional annotation from Spring)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot parameter `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is [set to `true` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222934/5380322).

I think you should turn it to `false`.

From java-doc:

> Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request.

Comment: Did not even know that option existing.  Thanks!