# Database Connections are open until http request is not complete

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have spring-boot application with JPA and Hibernate as ORM. I am using Hikaricp for connection pooling. So I have an api that fetch some records form the database apply some business logic and returns the result to client. Since the business logic have some heavy task(calling another api) to complete.

I was expecting the database connection should be return back to pool since records fetched successfully and nothing to do with that connection but the connection is still open (getting connection leak by HikariCP (leakDetectionThreshold=5000))

Hikari config.

`hikari:
  idleTimeout: 10000
  connectionTimeout: 60000
  maximumPoolSize: 10
  minimumIdle: 2
  poolName: gor-srms
  leakDetectionThreshold: 5000`

Database configuration class

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "srmsEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "srmsTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.gor.platform.srms.service.dao"})

```
public class SrmsDatabaseConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Autowired
JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

@Bean(name = "srmsDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("srms.db.driver"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("srms.db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("srms.db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("srms.db.password"));
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("hikari.idleTimeout")));
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("hikari.connectionTimeout")));
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("hikari.maximumPoolSize")));
    dataSource.setPoolName(environment.getProperty("hikari.poolName"));
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("hikari.minimumIdle")));
    dataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("hikari.leakDetectionThreshold")));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "srmsEntityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("srms.entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
    lef.setPersistenceUnitName(environment.getProperty("srms.hibernate.unit_name"));
    lef.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lef.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "srmsTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
}

@Bean(name = "srmsEntityManager")
public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}
```

}

Repository class

```
public interface ServiceRequestDao extends Dao<MServiceRequest, Long> {
@Query(value = "Native query.....", nativeQuery = true)
Long getParentId(@Param("childId") Long childId);
```

}

Comment: Show/see your code so we/you can find the leak

Comment: How are using using the connection from  pool ? I believe you are using `@Transactional`,In this case the connection will be released only after the method is returned. The way to fix this is create a separate method which just does database operations and add transaction to it. If that's not possible use programatic transaction and commit when you are done with database operations.

Comment: @user7294900 let me know if anything else required. Just for info even when I tested by calling JPA's findOne() method I end up with same issue.

Comment: Where is the code that execute the statement?

Comment: I am not using @Transactional. I did create a separate method but not worked.

Comment: Your lead detection threshold is 5 seconds. If a connection is in use for more then 5 seconds you will get a warning. Hikari can only see if a connection is checked out from the pool not if it is actually being used. So you probably want/need to increase the threshold for leak detection.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right. Fetching record form database is just taking few millis but the problem is why the connection is not returned to pool?

Comment: Because it remains open for the duration of the transaction... Everything is part of the transaction not only fetching the data.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot

Comment: @AlanHay already seen, didn't help.