# How is the entity being saved to the database without a transaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

I am able to save an entity without `@Transactional` in my Spring Boot application. I only noticed this because I wasn't able to update an entity until I added `@Transactional` to the `save` method within `EmployeeService.java`.

I don't have `@Transactional` annotated at the class level. The only other place it is found is on methods in my Service layer that do not pertain to the `save` method. My `EmployeeDAO` does not extend `JPARepository`. It is annotated with `@Repository`. I have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency. I am not manually beginning or committing a transaction either.

`EmployeeRestController.java`

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    employee.setId(0);

    employeeService.save(employee);
}
```

`EmployeeService.java`

```
public void save(Employee employee) {
    emplDAO.save(employee);
}
```

`EmployeeDAO.java`

```
@Override
public void save(Employee employee) {
    Session currentSession = em.unwrap(Session.class);

    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(employee);
}
```

Comment: By default `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is set to `true`. Probably it is the reason

Comment: @caco3 This was the exact cause. Thank you for clarifying. Can you provide more detail as to why this is the case?  This is the first time I have encountered open-in-view, as I am new to Spring.

Comment: @caco3 Also, I don't know how to upvote or mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You couldn't because it is a comment:) I've posted an answer with some related links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Spring Boot Web applications `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is set to `true`.

Most probably it is the reason

From [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-in-web-environment):

> If you are running a web application, Spring Boot by default registers `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` to apply the “Open EntityManager in View” pattern, to allow for lazy loading in web views. If you do not want this behavior, you should set `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false` in your `application.properties`.

**See also**:

- [What is this `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)
- [The Open Session In View Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/)
- [Log a warning on startup when spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled but user has not explicitly opted in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107)