# Spring boot 2 property spring.jpa.open-in-view=true is causing IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed on shutdown

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I created a sample spring boot 2.1.5.Release project with h2 database.

When I am trying to shutdown the application, it is throwing `IllegalStateException: EnityManager is closed`.

I am using `@PersistantContext` with `@Transactional`.

My application is not designed to support any asynchronous task. I even tried `WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = true` for `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but still showing the same exception while shutdown.

Later I found about this jpa property and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot) post, then I tried with `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` and `IllegalStateException` is resolved.
Here I learned that `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is recommended to set to false.

But I still don't understand with spring boot default setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`, why my application was throwing an exception.

How can I handle this scenario with `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` where it is not throwing `IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed`.

You can refer my uploaded code on github [here](https://github.com/sarvya521/auto-complete-service/).

Stacktrace when the application is shutting down:

```
[INFO ] 2019-06-17 13:20:09.572 [Thread-9] ThreadPoolTaskExecutor []- Shutting down ExecutorService 'locationPageExecutor'
[INFO ] 2019-06-17 13:20:09.575 [Thread-9] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean []- Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[ERROR] 2019-06-17 13:20:09.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] AutoCompleteExceptionHandler []- java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
[ERROR] 2019-06-17 13:20:09.584 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] [dispatcherServlet] []- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:531) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:496) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:679) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.createEntityManager(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:170) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.preHandle(OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.preHandle(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:57) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1034) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at com.ac.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:25) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
[ERROR] 2019-06-17 13:20:09.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] AutoCompleteExceptionHandler []- java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Can you please include the stacktrace?

Comment: How are you doing the shutdown? Looks like during shutdown there is still a request being handled. Which fails because the shutdown has already started to close the application context and destroying the beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried shutdown by killing the process. I tried it with actuator as well.

Comment: Actuator as in `/shutdown`? Regardless there is a request coming in, do you have monotoring enabled? Or Eureka or ?. All those things periodically poll the application using a web request, even if the application is shutting down (the external process doesn't know).

Comment: I can say there is no monitoring enabled for this. Moreover it is one atomic service without any dependency on cloud like eureka. There was a hystrix dependency added but no implementation but even when I remove hystrix support, it is still showing the exception.

Comment: What does  com.ac.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:25)  do?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added CorsFilter for CORS support. Line 25 is supposed to continue request after adding CORS headers. I am now worried you are blaming this line for the entire problem.

Comment: No don't worry. It's the OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor that causes the exception. But it's strange that there seems to be a HTTP request during shutdown