# Springboot 2 controller integration test transactional (lazy-loading) session issue

Tags: spring-boot

#### Issue

I had an Hibernate lazy loading issue when using Postman to send a reqeust derectly to a Springboot service endpoint, which is bacause I have a collection marked as FetchType.Lazy in an entity and this issue can be resolved by marking the service method as `@Transactional`.

However, if I remove that `@Transactional`, my Springboot controller test still passed without any Hibernate lazy loading issue.

This looks like all of the Springboot controller integration tests are always transactional. But I couldn't find any official document about it. So, my question is, is it correct?

For my integration test, I use the annotations below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
```

Comment: Tests should not be transactional for SpringBootTest by default. The only thing that comes to mind - do you have `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` configured in application.properties?

Comment: Thanks @Josef for you comment and that is the exact issue. 
The explicit config `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` can solve my problem.
I have compared the testing profile with others. The other profiles have truned `spring.jpa.open-in-view` off, But test profile still use the spring default one, which is `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Josef said in comment above, my issue here is about default Spring jpa config `spring.jpa.oepn-in-view=true`. For more details, please read:

- [What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view