# Spring Boot : Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, compiler-errors

What`s wrong with my spring boot ? What I have to do ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlzcZ.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From Version 2.0 onwards Spring boot gives a warning when OSIV (Open Session in View) is enabled. To remove this warning you can add the following properties in your `application.properties` file. See more about [OSIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot?).

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
```