# hibernate running error, restart normally

Tags: java, hibernate

The program runs for a period of time and always reports an error, restarting and returning to normal, the error is as follows：

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statementat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626)at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)at net.skycloud.platform.user.repository.KeycloakGroupDao.findAll(KeycloakGroupDao.java:111)at net.skycloud.platform.user.service.UserGroupService.getAllUserGroups(UserGroupService.java:247)at net.skycloud.platform.user.api.rest.UserController.searchUserAndGroup(UserController.java:362)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statementat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2122)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2059)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2181)at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)... 52 common frames omittedCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closedat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515)at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)... 67 common frames omitted
```

I hope to fix this bug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a database **operations** **level** exception using **EntityManager** or any other session manager (which is not your case) as exception suggest, how ever it can have many reasons such database has **closed** the **connection** or network terminated the connection socket, and to solve it you can configure to keep the connection alive but remember you can not hold the [**hibernate**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) session alive for long time by default .

Also you may have look on [**OSIV**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222934/15758781) anti pattern.