# Datasource switching for read-write operations in spring JPA within the same HTTP request

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using **`AbstractRoutingDataSource`** I have implemented read-write Datasource separation in the HTTP request label (essentially assigning a request to a DataSource and sticking with it for the entire request)

In my case, first I have to fetch some data, modify those data and then persist in the database, **here first I need READ-ONLY Datasource then UPDATABLE within the same HTTP request.**
Example:

```
StudentEntity entity= studentRepository.findById(1);//need read-only datasource
              entity.setName("David");

              entity= studentRepository.save(entity);//need updateable datasource
```

Could anyone please help me with how can I achieve this?
I am struggling for two days.

Answer (score 0):

I have been implement solution like this before.
Thinking of 2 verse of database connection.
You need 2 datasources bean with 2 jdbcTemplates as well, all need to be named `@Bean("beanName")`
(assign the default one as @Primary for prevent some default process of Spring)

Then @Autowired those 2 beans with `@Qualifer("beanName")`

But I not sure that this idea is can be apply to the JPA or not.

Comment: Thank you paranaaan.
Actually, I don't want to handle at the programming level but rather do with configuration using the AOP concept. I have already implemented that using `AbstractRoutingDataSource` (check) but it switches datasource only once for any HTTP request, what I want is to choose datasource for each DB operation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, have to put this in `application.properties`

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

Please go to the below link for an explanation.

[What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)