# How do I log when Hibernate lazily loads data outside a transaction when enable_lazy_load_no_trans is true?

Tags: hibernate

I know that `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` is considered an anti-pattern an the proper way is to use `EntityGraphs` or FETCH JOINs.  However, it is a good developer productivity gain initially.

What I want to know is which **specific** logger do I enable and at what level such that I would see when Hibernate performs lazy loading without a transaction?