# Spring Data JPA infinite recursion when retrieving by id

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm running into an issue to retrieve an object by its id.
I got a model "Playground" and a "PlaygroundComment". Where Playground holds a list of PlaygroundComments and has a OneToMany relation. I can create new PlaygroundComments but once i try to getById i get the infinite recursion.
Here is the code:

PlaygroundCommentController:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            logger.error(LogBuilder.parameterNotSet(ParameterEnum.ID.name()));
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(
                    LogBuilder.parameterNotSet(
                            ParameterEnum.ID.name()
                    ));
        }

        logger.info(LogBuilder.attemptToGet(PlaygroundComment.class.getSimpleName(), id));

        PlaygroundComment result = playgroundCommentService.getById(id);

        if (result == null) {
            logger.error(LogBuilder.NO_CONTENT);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } else {
            logger.info(LogBuilder.objectGetSuccess(result));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }
    }
```

Playground:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "playgrounds")
public class Playground {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "playground", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PlaygroundComment> playgroundComments;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "playground", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ReturnVisit> returnVisits;

    public Playground() {
    }

    public Playground(Long id, String street, String city, List<PlaygroundComment> playgroundComments, List<ReturnVisit> returnVisits) {
        this.id = id;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.playgroundComments = playgroundComments;
        this.returnVisits = returnVisits;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public List<PlaygroundComment> getPlaygroundComments() {
        return playgroundComments;
    }

    public void setPlaygroundComments(List<PlaygroundComment> playgroundComments) {
        this.playgroundComments = playgroundComments;
    }

    public List<ReturnVisit> getReturnVisits() {
        return returnVisits;
    }

    public void setReturnVisits(List<ReturnVisit> returnVisits) {
        this.returnVisits = returnVisits;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

PlaygroundComment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "playground_comments")
public class PlaygroundComment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "playground_id", nullable = false)
    private Playground playground;

    public PlaygroundComment() {
    }

    public PlaygroundComment(Long id, String content, Date timestamp, User user, Playground playground) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.user = user;
        this.playground = playground;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Playground getPlayground() {
        return playground;
    }

    public void setPlayground(Playground playground) {
        this.playground = playground;
    }
}
```

PlaygroundCommentService:

```
    @Override
    public PlaygroundComment getById(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            logger.error(LogBuilder.parameterNotSet(ParameterEnum.ID.name()));
            return null;
        }
        logger.info(LogBuilder.attemptToGet(PlaygroundComment.class.getSimpleName(), id));

        Optional<PlaygroundComment> optionalResult = playgroundCommentRepository.findById(id);

        if (optionalResult.isPresent()) {
            PlaygroundComment result = optionalResult.get();

            logger.info(LogBuilder.objectGetSuccess(result));

            return result;
        } else {
            logger.error(LogBuilder.objectGetFail(PlaygroundComment.class.getSimpleName(), id));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Could anyone see why this is occuring?
Thanks in advance!

The code in question is what ive tried.

Comment: Put `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` annotations to the relations.

Comment: Stop using entity classes in your API. Learn about proper 3tier architecture

Comment: @Slevin Oh my... really that simple.. I'd kiss you if i could right now haha! Thanks a ton, been looking at it long enough to wanting to call it a day!

Comment: @Jens On it, thanks for pointing that out. I assume you're meaning using DTO's for data transfer instead of the models?

Comment: Yes exectly that is what I mean

Comment: Glad to could help you. But you still have to understand why this happened, either because you tried to take a look at your response inside a Debugger who tried to pull the missing entities when printing them through a serialization or some other serializing channel thingie. Anyhow, you always should hint the relations with who's the master and who's the slave. - Since you put `LAZY` onto `OneToMany` a plain JPA query would break here by default, but something else further on your workflow tried to lazyload and that's where your problem started.

Comment: @Slevin It happened as i tried retrieving solely the PlaygroundComment object by its id so it did not try to LAZY load as it did not involve retrieving the Playground object with the list of comments. 
So im leaning towards it being a serialization issue. And those annotations being used mostly to prevent infinite recursion (as ive just learned), i'd say it was serialization. 
So if i understand the whole thing correctly, the JsonBackReference prevented the circular reference by specifically ignoring the Playground object during serialization, correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yes, something tried to serialize your result and wanted access to the @OneToMany List, which started the recursion, maybe the LogBuilder.

Comment: Since you seem to have still an open Transaction running this time, no lazy initialization exception was thrown. You should also annotate the service methods which access later on the repositories with dedicated `Transactional`s. And better in principal is to not go for OSIV pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222934/13609359 https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view

Comment: @Slevin Most definitely going to read into pro/anti OSIV. I genuinely appreciate your help and that you try to make me get a better understanding not just by simply spoon feeding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when @ManyToOne and @OneToMany are returned as JSON, they end up calling each other infinitely. Please add @JsonIgnore on one side.

Additionally, a fundamental solution is to return it as a DTO class.

One reason is that if the entity is returned as is, any change in the entity will cause a change in the API spec.

I hope it will be of help.