# Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following logic in Spring Boot 3

Controller Layer:

````
```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("option")
public class OptionController {

    private final OptionService optionService;
    @Autowired
    public OptionController(OptionService optionService) {
        this.optionService = optionService;
    }

    @GetMapping("POCPostgreSQL")
    public ResponseEntity<String> POCSaveListOfAccumulatedPremiumsToPostgreSQL(){
        optionService.saveAllAccumulatedPremiums(new ArrayList<>());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new String("POCPostgreSQL is done"));
    }
}
```
````

Service Layer:

````
```
public interface OptionService {
    void saveAllAccumulatedPremiums();
}


@Service
public class OptionServiceImpl implements OptionService{
    private final OptionPostgreSQLRepository optionPostgreSQLRepository;
    @Autowired
    public OptionServiceImpl(OptionPostgreSQLRepository optionPostgreSQLRepository) {
        this.optionPostgreSQLRepository = optionPostgreSQLRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAllAccumulatedPremiums() {
        POC_ETL_ALL_AccumulatedPremium();
    }

    public void POC_ETL_ALL_AccumulatedPremium(){
        Path startPath = Paths.get("/data");
        try (Stream<Path> folderPaths = Files.walk(startPath, 1)) {
            List<Path> sortedFolders = folderPaths
                    .filter(Files::isDirectory)  // only consider directories
                    .filter(path -> !path.equals(startPath))  // exclude the startPath itself
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> path.getFileName().toString()))  // sort by folder name (which represents date)
                    .toList();

            for (Path folderPath : sortedFolders) {
                Instant folderBegin = Instant.now();
                System.out.println("Processing folder: " + folderPath);

                try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(folderPath)) {
                    paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)  // only consider files (ignore directories)
                            .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".csv"))  // only process .csv files
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> path.getFileName().toString()))  // sort by folder name (which represents timestamp)
                            .forEach(path -> {
                                try {
                                    List<AccumulatedPremium> premiums = parseCsvFile(path.toString(), AccumulatedPremium::fromCsvRecord);
                                    System.out.println(path);
                                    optionPostgreSQLRepository.saveAllAndFlush(premiums);


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Instant folderFinish = Instant.now();
                long timeElapsed = Duration.between(folderBegin, folderFinish).toSeconds();
                System.out.println("Time taken for folder " + folderPath.getFileName() + ": " + timeElapsed + " seconds");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<T> parseCsvFile(String filePath, Function<CSVRecord, T> recordMapper) {
        List<T> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath));
             CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                     .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                     .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                     .withTrim())) {

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                T record = recordMapper.apply(csvRecord);
                recordsList.add(record);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return recordsList;
    }
}
```
````

DAO Layer:

````
```
public interface OptionPostgreSQLRepository extends JpaRepository<AccumulatedPremium, Long> {
    
}
```
````

Entity:

```
     @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "accumulated_premium_temp")
    public class AccumulatedPremium {
        private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "accumulated_premium_temp")
        @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "accumulated_premium_temp", // Logical name used in the @GeneratedValue annotation to refer to this generator
            sequenceName = "accumulated_premium_temp_id_seq", // Actual name of the sequence in the database
            allocationSize = 1000 // The increment size for the sequence (change this as per your requirement)
        )
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "local_date_time")
        private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    
        @Column(name = "ticker")
        private String ticker;
    
        @Column(name = "strike_price")
        private double strikePrice;
    
        @Column(name = "expire_date")
        private Date expireDate;
    
        @Column(name = "premium")
        private double premium;
    
        public AccumulatedPremium(LocalDateTime localDateTime, String ticker, double strikePrice, Date expireDate, double premium) {
            this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
            this.ticker = ticker;
            this.strikePrice = strikePrice;
            this.expireDate = expireDate;
            this.premium = premium;
        }
    
        // Static method to map CSVRecord to AccumulatedPremium
        public static AccumulatedPremium fromCsvRecord(CSVRecord record) {
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(record.get("TimeStamp"), dateTimeFormatter); // Use "TimeStamp" as it appears in the CSV
            String ticker = record.get("Ticker");
            double strikePrice = Double.parseDouble(record.get("StrikePrice"));
            Date expireDate = Date.valueOf(record.get("ExpirationDate"));
            double premium = Double.parseDouble(record.get("Premium"));
    
            return new AccumulatedPremium(
                localDateTime,
                ticker,
                strikePrice,
                expireDate,
                premium
            );
        }
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8091
# DataSource Configuration
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
# JPA/Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Optional: If you want to view the batch operations in logs (turn off in production for better performance)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
# DataSource settings
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
```

The restful API exposed in controller layer is designed for ETL purpose to load 400 * 480 CSV files into PostgreSQL single table. The performance is getting slower and slower when the spring boot project start to loading data from CSV files to PostgreSQL. I have checked in Eclipse Memory Analyzer and the reason when heap is growing up in linear while the ETL workload is working is due to hibernate stateful entity context hashmap and identity map. As you can see, I have already enable batch insertion and Transactional boundaries to flush persistent entities in hibernate cache. But the elder gen in heap is still growing in linear due to hashmap and identity map mentioned above. And even stranger, if I move all the same logic in to SpringBoot class as following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    OptionPostgreSQLRepository optionPostgreSQLRepository;
    @Autowired
    OptionService optionService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        optionService.saveAllAccumulatedPremiums();
    }
    public void POC_ETL_ALL_AccumulatedPremium(){
        Path startPath = Paths.get(/data");
        try (Stream<Path> folderPaths = Files.walk(startPath, 1)) {
            List<Path> sortedFolders = folderPaths
                    .filter(Files::isDirectory)  // only consider directories
                    .filter(path -> !path.equals(startPath))  // exclude the startPath itself
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> path.getFileName().toString()))  // sort by folder name (which represents date)
                    .toList();

            for (Path folderPath : sortedFolders) {
                Instant folderBegin = Instant.now();
                System.out.println("Processing folder: " + folderPath);

                try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(folderPath)) {
                    paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)  // only consider files (ignore directories)
                            .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".csv"))  // only process .csv files
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> path.getFileName().toString()))  // sort by folder name (which represents timestamp)
                            .forEach(path -> {
                                try {
                                    List<AccumulatedPremium> premiums = parseCsvFile(path.toString(), AccumulatedPremium::fromCsvRecord);
                                    System.out.println(path);

                                    Instant postgreStart = Instant.now();
                                    optionPostgreSQLRepository.saveAll(premiums);
                                    Instant postgreFinish = Instant.now();
                                    long timeElapsed = Duration.between(postgreStart, postgreFinish).toMillis();
                                    System.out.println("Time taken for postgre " + ": " + timeElapsed + " milliseconds");



                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Instant folderFinish = Instant.now();
                long timeElapsed = Duration.between(folderBegin, folderFinish).toSeconds();
                System.out.println("Time taken for folder " + folderPath.getFileName() + ": " + timeElapsed + " seconds");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<T> parseCsvFile(String filePath, Function<CSVRecord, T> recordMapper) {
        List<T> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath));
             CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                     .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                     .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                     .withTrim())) {

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                T record = recordMapper.apply(csvRecord);
                recordsList.add(record);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return recordsList;
    }
}
```

The performance is getting awesome and the heap usage never exceed more than 100 MB.

One more strange thing is that for application.properties configuration, I open the sql statistic:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

But the statistic will only be printed out when I run the logic in springboot class. If I run it via calling restful endpoint in controller, the statistic does not print out and the heap can linearly growing into 7GB after hours of execution due to that identityHashMap and HashMap. Again, I saw in Memory Analyzer that it is due to hibernate class which I assume is used by Spring Data JPA and shall be cleaned up by the flush in saveALlAndFlush API in spring data jpa.

Could anyone give me some advice or hints how to dig deeper to solve this problem?

Comment: flushing is not clearing the first level cache. What you should do is instead of collecting everything in a list and then do `saveAll`. Should call `save` for each individual row, keep a counter and if that counter exceeds your batch size (in this case 1000) do a `flush` and `clear` on the entitymanager (still a 1000 is high you want it a bit lower probably). If you don't clear the entity manager the firs tlevel cache will fill up. And because of dirty checking (it checks each element in the first level cache) it will progressivly get slower and slower and slower if you don't clear.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be caused by Open Session In View.

Could you try adding

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

and check whether it helps?

For more context:
[What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)